# How to display direct URL of Google Custom Search query?

Tags: google-search

I tried adding a Google Custom Search Engine to my Firefox search bar. The search URL Firefox created looked something like this -- containing `<my-custom-search-engine-ID>` and the `<query>`:

`https://www.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=<my-custom-search-engine-id>?search=<my-query>`

But -- for some reason, this direct URL gives a `400` error: "400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request."

I can still use my Custom Search Engine, but only directly from the Google page. A couple of years ago this kind of direct linking/querying worked, though. What has Google changed since, and how can I find out the direct URL to my GCS queries?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**: A working solution seems to be creating a custom `search.html` page (using the code obtained from your GCSE settings). But maybe a direct link to Google's default results page is still possible as well?

Comment: Please add answers as separate answers and mark them as accepted. Don't edit them into your question.

Comment: it was something I figured out myself, not an answer proposed by others. But, sure, I'll just answer my question myself then. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: This case happens often and the site encourages users to answer their own questions. There is nothing immoral about it. :)

Comment: @marttt does this solution still work ? no luck with it here

Comment: @hulkingtickets no idea, i havent hacked around with my cse for quite a while. sorry.